# Migrate question on witty/rewarding loading messages

Tags: support, migration, migrate

I've seen over my career a few instances of witty loading messages, and they definitely improved my experience with the site. While working at Yahoo! for instance, we had a set of haikus displayed while Mail was loading up.

Here's [a question from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182112/what-are-some-funny-loading-statements-to-keep-users-amused) on that topic. It was deleted as it rightly doesn't belong there as of late (after [SO lost its fun side](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-so-su-programmers-questions-list)).

[image]

Any chance to migrate it here?

Answer (score 3):

That question has since been deleted so can only be viewed by users with +10k rep on StackOverflow. I am not such a user, however looking at the title of it:

> What are some funny loading statements to keep users amused

I would say that no, it's not suited to UX StackExchange. Or any Stack site really. 'What are some' questions, just like "Can I have some examples of x type of interface" don't really work in a Q&A format because they are questions without an answer.

As Jeff Atwood states in his blog [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/):

> **Real questions have *answers*, not *items* or *ideas* or *opinions.***

This is also covered in the FAQ section of all the Stack Exchange sites:

https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

So yeah, unless the question content is not what the question title suggests then I don't think it's a suitable question for the site.

As with many fun questions, just because they related to the same field as the site (user experience) doesn't mean it's a *suitable* question for the site.

Finally, even if it were suitable for the site, questions that are over 60 days old can't be migrated anyway.

Comment: I don't know about the title, but there surely must useful content in the answers to that question. An insightful loading message is better than "Loading...". a) How can one ask for such messages within the rules of UX? b) How can we salvage useful content from those answers?

Comment: "questions that are over 60 days old can't be migrated anyway" - really? Why? Seems like a sheer loss of value. To [quote Jeff himself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50069/why-are-we-deleting-instead-of-merging/50106#50106), _"I wish people wouldn't delete questions with good answers. You're destroying the useful contributions of your peers! 

Flag these for moderator attention instead and suggest a merge!"_

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. How did you get it without being a 10k user?

Comment: [Here's the reason for 60 day migration limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days). As for the screenshot; I have friends in powerful places! (Or I asked one of the SO mods to get a screenshot for me).

Comment: And yes, questions about error messages can be made suitable, provided they're answerable. Such as: [Should error messages apologise](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31359/should-error-messages-apologize)

Comment: I think I've seen that question before deletion; don't think this one in particular should be migrated. The general topic is relevant to UX but the specific question is more the topic for a funny subreddit than practical Q&A